# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ajax jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

got an error of **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :** from JSONP

here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://lc-txtconnect5.globe.com.ph/api/mts/validateuser',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback"
        });
    });

   function localJsonpCallback(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
```

the response from server **{"response":{"code":200,"token":"46847c41ed62ee72c8de61ad97f7db6343d5e049"}}**

Comment: your response from the server should include the jsonp callback function. ie. your response should be `localJsonpCallback(CURRENT RESPONSE DATA)` https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 0):

The API you are requesting from doesn't appear to support JSONP, try JSON instead.

Comment: NOTE: if that site doesn't issue CORS headers, then JSON wont work either

Answer (score 0):

your response should be `localJsonpCallback({"response":{"code":200,"token":"46847c41ed62ee72c8de61ad97f7db6343d5e049"}})`,and the `localJsonpCallback` is a function defined in your code